# Linux sscanf function doesn't fill variable

Tags: c, linux, parsing, scanf

I am currently writing an FTP server and I need to parse the ip and port of a remote server from an input string buffer in the following format:

```
xxx,xxx,xxx,xxx,yyy,zzz
```

where:

- `xxx` stands for an ip address octet in decimal
- `yyy` is round((remote port number) / 256)
- `zzz` is (remote port number) % 256

For example: `127,0,0,1,123,64` means `ip = 127.0.0.1` and `port = 31552`.

I am currently using `sscanf` to extract the following fields from the input string buffer:

```
sscanf(str, "%u,%u,%u,%u,%u,%u", ret_ip, &ip[0], &ip[1], &ip[2], &temp1, &temp2) == 6
```

where:

- str is the input buffer
- ret_ip is of type `uint32_t`
- ip's are of type `uint32_t`
- temp1 and temp2 are of type `unsigned short int`

Example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    uint32_t ip[4];
    unsigned short int temp, temp1;

    if (sscanf("127,0,0,1,142,214", "%u,%u,%u,%u,%u,%u", &ip[0], &ip[1], &ip[2], &ip[3], &temp, &temp1) == 6)
    {
        printf("%u : %u", temp, temp1);
    }

    return (0);
}
```

My problem is that, for valid string, the value of **temp1** is always 0 (zero), i.e. all the other variables are filled according to string except the **temp1**. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scanf` isn't as forgiving of format specifier mismatches as `printf` is. The specifiers need to match exactly or else you invoke undefined behavior.

For `unsigned short` use `%hu`. `%u` is for `unsigned int`.

There are no direct format specifiers for types like `uint32_t`. You need to [use a macro from `inttypes.h`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26618443/how-to-use-int16-t-or-int32-t-with-functions-like-scanf): `"%" SCNu32`.

All together:

```
if (sscanf(str, "%" SCNu32 ",%" SCNu32 ",%" SCNu32 ",%" SCNu32 ",%hu,%hu", ret_ip, &ip[0], &ip[1], &ip[2], &temp1, &temp2) == 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

The followings are added to this answer compare to the available answers:

- Extracting the IP address octets as `unsigned char` and then store them as a single IP address of size `uint_32` instead of having an array of `uint_32`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10283942/5412470) for more information.
- Validating against the `sscanf` output.
- The `%hu` scan code is used for reading `unsigned short` and the
  `%hhu` scan code is used for reading `unsigned char`.
- Verifying the process of IP address conversion from `string` to `unitt_32` using [inet_pton](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_pton.3.html) and from `unitt_32` to `string` using [inet_ntop](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_ntop.3.html). Read [this section](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/inet_ntopman.html) of Beej's networking book if you want to learn more.

and here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    unsigned char ip_octects[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    uint32_t ip = 0;
    unsigned short r1 = 0, r2 = 0;
    unsigned char *str_c = "127,0,0,1,142,214";

    if(sscanf(str_c, "%hhu,%hhu,%hhu,%hhu,%hu,%hu", &ip_octects[0],
                    &ip_octects[1], &ip_octects[2], &ip_octects[3], &r1, &r2) == 6){

        printf("Extracted ip : port: %hhu.%hhu.%hhu.%hhu:%hu:%hu\n",
                ip_octects[0], ip_octects[1], ip_octects[2], ip_octects[3], r1, r2);

        ip = ip_octects[0]       | ip_octects[1] << 8 |
             ip_octects[2] << 16 | ip_octects[3] << 24;
        printf("unit32_t  ip  value: %zu\n", ip);

        /* We're done but lets verify the results using inet_pton() and inet_ntop() */
        unsigned char *str_d = "127.0.0.1";
        char str[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
        struct sockaddr_in sa;
        if(inet_pton(AF_INET, str_d, &(sa.sin_addr)) < 1){
            perror("error: invalid input for inet_pton"); exit(1);
        }
        printf("inet_pton ip  value: %zu\n",sa.sin_addr);
        if(inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(sa.sin_addr), str, INET_ADDRSTRLEN) == NULL){
            perror("error: invalid input for inet_ntop"); exit(1);
        }
        printf("inet_ntop str value: %s\n", str);
    }
    else{
        perror("error: invalid input for sscanf"); exit(1);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Followling is my code which seems to work and print correct results.

```
  char sentence []="127,0,0,1,123,64";
  uint16_t ret_ip;
  uint16_t ip1, ip2, ip3;
  uint16_t temp1, temp2;

  sscanf(sentence, "%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d", &ret_ip, &ip1, &ip2, &ip3, &temp1, &temp2);

  printf("%d, %d\n", temp1, temp2);
```

Comment: `%d` is for `int`. It is a mistake to use it for `uint16_t`.