# C++ how to read __int16_t integer using scanf function

Tags: c++, scanf

using **scanf** to read a specified width integer.

```
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main(){
   __int16_t a;
   __int32_t b;
   scanf("%d %d", &a, &b)
   return 0;
}
```

there is a compiler warning that **format specifier "%d" requires 'int *' arg instead of '__int16_t *'**
so how to fix it?
BTW C++11 is not permitted!

Comment: There is no format specifier for `__int24_t` because that is not a standard data type - maybe your compiler has some special extension for that (though it's a pretty odd width for an integer type)

Comment: Also you should probably prefer using C++11 [fixed-width integer types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer)

Comment: `scanf` supports a limited set of data types. Have a look at `format` parameter description in [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf), to familiarize yourself with what is supported.

Comment: in C++ use `std::cin` instead. It's much type-safer

Answer (score 2):

The standard `std::scanf` only supports standard types. Unless your standard library documents a format specifier that allows the use of non-standard types, you cannot use it to read into non standard types. If it does, then simply follow their documentation.

You could try to first scan into a standard type, then mask the extra bits (if any), and convert. If the input wouldn't overflow the intended target types, then the masking is superfluous.

```
long temp_a, temp_b; // could use short or int for temp_a
std::scanf("%ld %ld", &temp_a, &temp_b);
__int16_t a = temp_a & 0xffff;
__int32_t b = temp_b & 0xffffffff;
```

---

For completeness, if one can use C++11, they have standard fixed width types:

```
std::int16_t a;
std::int32_t b;
std::scanf("%" PRId16 "%" PRId32, &a, &b)
```

---

Or, if your streaming library has overloads for the non-standard types, use `std::cin`. That way you can deal with invalid input.

Answer (score 0):

`__int16_t` is presumably a (compiler-specific) type that is a 16-bit signed integer.   `scanf()` does not generally support such compiler-specific types (and, if it does, it will require a format specifier that is specific to your compiler and library).

In the following, I assume a compiler that supports `__int16_t` as a 16-bit signed integral type, and `scanf()` does not provide any way to read one.

```
 long int some_int;    //  range at least [-2147483647,2147483647]
 __int16_t a;
 if (scanf("%ld ", &some_int) == 1)
 {
      //   report error if some_int outside range a __int16_t can represent

      a = some_int;
 }
 else
 {
       // an error occurred
 }
```

I don't use `int` and the `%d` format specifier in the above, because the C++ standard only requires an `int` to be able to represent the range of `-32767` to `32767` (albeit permitting a larger range).   It is conceivable that `int` for your compiler can represent the range `-32678` to `32767` but that an `__int16_t` represents the range `-32767` to `32768`.   In such a setting, the above code may not handle input of `32768` correctly if it uses `int` instead of `long int`.

Personally, I'd probably try using a C++ `istream`  (e.g.   `std::cin >> a`) instead of C's `scanf()` because, practically, it is likely it likely to work.   The reason is that, if an implementation which supports a type like `__int16_t`, the effort to have included support in `istream` for it is less than the effort to support it in `scanf()`.

Comment: I suggest removing the space after `%ld` as it will discard whitespace characters _until the first non-whitespace character_ and that will block the input until additional non-whitespace characters are entered.

Answer (score -5):

Use '%d' for __int16_t. I do not know '__int24_t' exists. More here: [How to use int16_t or int32_t with functions like scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26618443/how-to-use-int16-t-or-int32-t-with-functions-like-scanf).

Comment: `Use '%d' for __int16_t` This will work if, and only if, `sizeof (int) == 2`, which is rarely the case on modern systems. In addition, this should have been a comment, rather than answer (yes, I know that you don't have enough rep for comments, but that does not mean, that you can post half-baked answers).

Comment: Also OP is getting a warning exactly when using `%d` for `__int16_t`